# Installing wear only apk without ADB or Android studio or eclipse

Tags: android, wear-os, software-distribution

I am working on an application, that is intended for Android wear devices only. I know Google play doesn't support apps that only run on wearable devices (not on handhelds), but this application is for internal purposes only.

I know these

1) I can install directly to wearable devices from eclipse/studio during debugging, just like I do it on handhelds

2) I can use adb command to install directly to wearable device.

But I have created a signed apk of the application, and I want to sent this build to client, who is not a developer and above 2 methods doesn't work. If I sent the apk to him by mail, is there any easy way for him to install it on his wearable?

Note : If it required, consider that client had a handheld device that can sync with this wearable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to build the *mobile-signed-apk*.

It will contain also the wear-apk. You can send the mobile-signed-apk to your client /by email for example) and he has to install this apk in his *handheld device* as a normal apk.

When the handheld app will connect with the wear, it will install/update the wear-apk on the wearable device.

Comment: So application should run on handheld as well. Is there any problem if the mobile version doesn't contain any Activity/UI element(like a background running service)?

Comment: The mobile app can be empty, without Activities, but you have to declare the same package in AndroidManifest for both.

Comment: got it, so that is an idea worth checking out. Thanks Gabriele

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: its stupid question but i am sorry for that,if app support android wear but user haven't wear watch then watch code remain installed in android device? or something else happens to it.

Comment: Yes. it is in your app. If you will connect a watch, the watch will receive the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload to your developer console it app as alpha and give access for client to alpha testing.

Comment: I haven't set eyes on a real device yet, so this might be a childish question. When I looked at the android wear emulator from my studio, there is no option to setup a mail account, open a browser to view a link etc. So how can he install it on the wear?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#Install

`When you're ready to publish your app to users, you embed the wearable app inside of the handheld app. When users install the handheld app from Google Play, a connected wearable automatically receives the wearable app.`

you can publish app as alpha

Comment: That requires us to have a handheld version of the app, right? More over, our app is for internal use only. So we are not thinking of uploading it to app store.